# How can I establish a websocket between two meteor apps?

Tags: meteor, socket.io

I want to have a the client of a Meteor app establish a permanent connection to the server of a distinct meteor app. socket.io seems to be the way to go for this type of connection.

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/TheGraduate/socket-io-client/commit/24b5f09a186b0a93751aa217887270fadf06316c) I can use socket.io with meteor and initiate the connection from the client of the first app, apparently like this:

```
var socket = io('http://app2.com');
socket.emit('ping', 'dummy');
```

How can I create a route to respond to this request from app2 server?

To make things a bit clearer:

```
               ----------------
              | client of app1 |
               ----------------
                            \   
                       want socket.io to run here
                               \  
 ----------------          ----------------
| server of app1 |        | server of app2 |
 ----------------          ----------------
```

Happy to answer any question you may have!